# paypal payment method for debit and credit card using php

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated Paypal REST API (rest-api-sdk-php) payment gateway in my site. for pay with debit and credit card. I tested that with sandbox, its working fine. some of the reason my live credential are in pending for direct card access.

```
            //paypal
            $cc_first_name      = (isset($_POST['card_holder_name']))? $_POST['card_holder_name'] : die("First Name Empty");
            $cc_last_name       = (isset($_POST["card_holder_last_name"]))? $_POST["card_holder_last_name"] : die("Last Name Empty");
            $cc_card_type       = (isset($_POST["credit_card_type"]))? $_POST["credit_card_type"] : die("Credit Card type Empty");
            $cc_card_number     = (isset($_POST['card_number']))? $_POST['card_number'] : die("Credit Card Number Empty");
            $cc_card_month      = (isset($_POST['expiry_month']))? $_POST['expiry_month'] : die("Expire Month Empty");
            $cc_card_year       = (isset($_POST['expiry_year']))? $_POST['expiry_year'] : die("Expire Year Empty");
            $cc_card_cvv2       = (isset($_POST['cvvCode']))? $_POST['cvvCode'] : die("CVV month empty");
            //paypal        


if($_POST["payment_method"] == "credit_card"){
    $credit_card = array(
        'type'=> $cc_card_type, 
        'number' => $cc_card_number, 
        'expire_month'=>$cc_card_month, 
        'expire_year'=>$cc_card_year, 
        'cvv2'=>$cc_card_cvv2,
        'first_name'=>$cc_first_name,
        'last_name'=>$cc_last_name
        );
    //pay directly using credit card information.
    $result = pay_direct_with_credit_card($credit_card, PP_CURRENCY , $total_amount, $items, '') ;
}
```

In that api code it checks only with credit card. they doesn't use any function to accept debit card. what i need is. can this code snippet accept debit card payement?

Answer (score 0):

It should works the same for debit card as long as it is valid for Live environment.